# monitor locations using for in loop in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

i am trying to pass all latitudes and longitudes to an array. How can i use for in loop to monitor the locations in swift. please give a sample to use for loop here.

```
 var latitudes = [Double]()
        var longitudes = [Double]()

        latitudes = [17.42704503,32.92343, 32.9222511, 32.9220601]
        longitudes = [78.43239323 ,-117.119527,-117.1185289 ,-117.118321]



            let geofenceRegionCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.42704503, 78.43239323);
            let geofenceRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: geofenceRegionCenter, radius: 100, identifier: "PlayaGrande");
            geofenceRegion.notifyOnExit = true;
            geofenceRegion.notifyOnEntry = true;
            self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: geofenceRegion)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: i am monitoring each and every locations as i am working on geofencing. How can i monitor 20 locations at a time using for in loop